# change datatype of a column in a datatable in C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a Data table where i am reading the values from a excel file, The datatype its taking is string. I have a column 4 with DateTime format. But its reading as string. How do i convert String to DateTime format. I just have one column to change the Datatype.

I have read the excel file using oledb connection and then loaded it to a datatable. I just want to change the datatype of string to DateTime for a particular column. The column contains the header as well.

Please help?

Comment: Please share your code about how you are fetching data from excel

Comment: Add new column as DateTime. Then convert and delete original column.

Answer (score 0):

if the record in a correct date format, event it's string, you can use

```
DateTime.Parse(tb.Rows[i][0].ToString()) - //this returns Date and Time
Datetime.Parse(tb.Rows[i][0].ToString()).ToShortDateString()  // this returns only the date.
```